# how to make safari browser compatible for salesforce.?

Tags: javascript, css, safari, salesforce

I have an problem like my application well and good run in chrome but in safari browser my save & cancel buttons are not with original position or not proper alignment. My application is developed in salesforce so i need help.
   I am attaching an screenshot this pages so we will helping for better understanding of problem.

In  Chrome[image]

In safari

[image]

Following html code for save and cancel

```html
  <div style="display: inline-block; float: left; margin-left:10px; width: 190px; margin-right: 0px; transition-property: margin-top; transition-duration: 500ms; position: fixed;">

    <a class="save"  onclick="jobsave();"  >

      <span >Save</span></a> 
    <br/><br/>
    <a class="cancel-btn" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open('/apex/FieldAwareConnectorPage','_self');">Cancel</a>

</div>
```

Following css for save and cancel button

```css
 .cancel-btn {
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    color: #6D6D6D;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #EEE;
    padding:10px 0;
     background-color: #1a82f7; 
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 50%, 0% 50%, from(#E3DDDD), to(#fff));
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #E3DDDD, #fff); 
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E3DDDD, #fff); 
     background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #E3DDDD, #fff);
     background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #E3DDDD, #fff);
     box-shadow:0 0 10px #E3DDDD inset;
     box-shadow: 0px -3px 10px #E3DDDD inset;
}
.cancel-btn:hover {
    background:none;
    box-shadow:0 0 0;
    text-decoration:none;
     color: #6D6D6D;
}
```

Comment: It has to do with browser compatibility... This link http://caniuse.com/ will tell you if the HTML/CSS is compatible with each browser and the version of that browser. If you post your code I can help you out but without knowing what your code looks like and just looking at a screenshot doesn't help much.

Comment: following css for save and cancel button.

Comment: what? post your HTML/CSS

Comment: i have posted my css

Comment: kk. and are you using the `<button>` html tag? or `<div>`

Comment: no i am using div inside <a> tag

Comment: lastly what version of safari are you using?

Comment: update it to 8.0.8 (latest) moving forward using in `<a>` tag on 5.1 shouldn't be the problem... can you please post the full source code not just the code for the buttons... it could be a problem related to positioning so I need to see your structure.

Comment: @JordanDavis i have update my html code.

Comment: kk yea you have a few errors give me a sec

Comment: first off though do you have the CSS for the `class="save" ` class... if so please post it...

Comment: let me mock something for you

Answer (score 0):

This semantic using HTML5 tags and responsive using a grid that will scale the elements.

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o7L9capq/1/)

Screenshot:

[image]

//HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>  
    <section id="main">
        <header>
            <h1>New Job</h1>
            <h2>Job Summary</h2>
            <hr>
        </header>
        <section id="widgets">
            <section id="area1">
                <form>
                    <input type="text" name="customer_location" placeholder="Customer & Location">
                    <input type="text" name="contact" placeholder="Contact">
                    <input type="text" name="asset" placeholder="Asset">
                </form>
            </section>
            <section id="area2">
                <form>
                    <textarea placeholder="Job Description"></textarea>
                    <p id="count">4096 remaining characters</p>
                </form>
            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
    <aside>
        <button onclick="">Save</button>
        <button onclick="">Cancel</button>
    </aside>
</body>
</html>
```

//CSS

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p{
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helevetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;

    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

}   
#main{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex: 80;
    flex: 80;

    padding: 3em;

    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
h1{
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 1em;
    font-size: 3em;
    background: #31D2D2;
}
h2{
    color: #7C7C7C;
}
#widgets{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;


}

#area1{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex: 20;
    flex: 20;

    padding: 1em;

    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#area2{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;

    padding: 1em;

    -webkit-flex: 80;
    flex: 80;   

}
form{
    cursor: default !important;

    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;

    background: #ECF0F1;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.3em;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    padding: 1.3em;
}
form>input{ 
    height: 2.5em;
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helevetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d5dadc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #7C7C7C;
    outline: none;
}
button{
    height: 2.5em;
    margin: .5em 1em;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helevetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
}
aside>button:nth-of-type(1){
    background: #2ECC71;
}

aside>button:nth-of-type(2){
    background: #7C7C7C;
}

aside>button:nth-of-type(1):hover{
    background: #40D47E;
}
aside>button:nth-of-type(2):hover{
    background: #9A9999;
}
button:active{
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
textarea{
    height: 10em;
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #d5dadc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #7C7C7C;
    outline: none;
        font-size: 1em;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light,"Helevetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial;

}
#count{
    font-style: italic;
    color: #ccc;
}
aside{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;

    -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;


    -webkit-flex: 20;
    flex: 20;

    z-index: 999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
    background: #ECF0F1;    


}
```